# Views Auto-Refresh: is there a way to deactivate the ''Please Wait" message

Tags: views, 7, ajax

I am building a live message tracker, and I am using 'Views Auto-Refresh" to update my list of messages every 5 seconds.  My problem: every time the page updates, a "Please Wait" message appears above mt view for a second, and bumps the content down, then back.  This is very annoying.  Is there a built in way to move or hide this message of will I need to use CSS to hide it?

Comment: just use css to set `display: none;` on the element.

Comment: I have done that, I just want / wish there was a better way.

Comment: Feel free to create a patch to the 3rd party module you're using and submit it for review to the module maintainer. Drupal is built by many many volunteers -- nothing is easy until someone makes it that way.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: see http://drupal.org/novice and https://drupal.org/patch